# numbers that can be formed using $\sum_{i=0}^n \pm2^i$

Tags: number-theory

Which numbers can be formed if we can choose the signs of $\sum_{i=0}^n \pm2^i$?

Comment: Do you mean $(\pm2)^i$ by any chance?

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you tried making the first few?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any odd integer.

$$\sum_{i=0}^n 2^i = 2^{n+1}-1$$

That's an odd number.

Now you're subtracting :

$$2\sum_{i=0}^n 2^i a_i$$

where $a_i$ is either $1$ or $0$

That's an even number.

Your sequence is formed by subtracting an even number from an odd number, which is an odd number.

Comment: Great answer. To be precise, any odd number between $-2^{n+1}+1$ and $2^{n+1}-1$. And there are $2^{n+1}$ such numbers, so each one has exactly one representation.

Answer (score 2):

Add $$2^{n+1}-1=\sum_{i=0}^n2^i$$ and you get

$$\sum_{i=0}^n2^i+\sum_{i=0}^n\pm_i2^i=2\sum_{i=0}^nb_i2^i$$ where the $b_i$ are $0$ or $1$.

So your numbers are

$$2m-2^{n+1}+1$$ where $m$ is any $n+1$ bits integer (leading zeroes allowed).

In other words, every other integer in $[1-2^{n+1},1+2^{n+1}]$.